# Puzzler solver program: How many different solutions are there to (1/a)+(1/b)+(1/c)+(1/d)+(1/e)+(1/f)+(1/g) = 1?

Tags: addition, puzzle, fractions

I wrote the python code below that solves and prints each possible solution for anything under 6 unit fractions, but given how I programmed it, it takes infinitely long to check for 7 fractions. Any ideas on how to modify the code to find all the possible solutions more efficienty?

```css
import sys
from fractions import Fraction


import os

#myfile = open('7fractions.txt', 'w')

max = 7 #>2 #THIS VARIABLE DECIDES HOW MANY FRACTIONS ARE ALLOWED
A = [0] * max
A[0] = 1

def printList(A):
 return str(A).strip('[]')

def sumList(A):
 sum = 0
 for i in A:
  if i != 0:
   sum += Fraction(1, i)
 return sum

def sumTest(A):
 sum = 0
 v = 0
 for i in range(0, len(A)):
  if A[i] == 0 and v == 0:
   v = Fraction(1,A[i-1])
  if v != 0:
   sum += v
  else: 
   sum += Fraction(1, A[i])
 return sum

def solve(n, A):
 if n == max - 2:
  while (sumTest(A) > 1):
   print(A)
   if sumList(A) < 1:
    e = 1 - sumList(A)
    if e.numerator == 1 and e.denominator>A[n-1]:
     A[n+1] = e.denominator
     #myfile.write(printList(A) + '\n')
     print(A)
     A[n+1] = 0
   A[n] += 1
 else:
  while (sumTest(A) > 1):
   if sumList(A) < 1:
    A[n+1] = A[n] + 1
    solve(n+1, A)
    A[n+1] = 0
   A[n] += 1

#execute
solve(0, A)
```